# How to clear a variable's memory, after the function is called the first time

Tags: javascript, variables, compare

I am trying to clear a variable's memory because the function works correctly only on the first call, later if I change a value in my input, the function works on the old input... Can I clean the old value somehow? I tried with x,y=undefined, but it doesn't work.

```
var btn = document.getElementById("mybutton");


btn.addEventListener("click", compareValue);
var x = Number(document.getElementById("value1").value);
var y = Number(document.getElementById("value2").value);
function compareValue (){
  if (x>y){window.alert("Value 1 bigger")
}else if(y>x){window.alert("Value 2 bigger")
}else{window.alert("Values are equal")};

document.getElementById("value1").value="";
document.getElementById("value2").value="";

x=undefined;
y=undefined;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply move the variable declarations inside the function passed to `addEventListener()` like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("mybutton");


btn.addEventListener("click",compareValue);

function compareValue(){
    var x = Number(document.getElementById("value1").value);
    var y = Number(document.getElementById("value2").value);
    if(x > y){
        window.alert("Value 1 bigger");
    }else if(y > x){
        window.alert("Value 2 bigger");
    }else{
        window.alert("Values are equal");
    }

    document.getElementById("value1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("value2").value = "";
};
```

This will cause them to be scoped to the inside of the `compareValue` function, and they'll be deleted when the function ends. (And they won't be accessible (or even exist) outside of that function.)